# Hibernate StaleObjectStateException while saving an Object

Tags: hibernate

I Have a two POJO Classes
 1. Profile.java
 2. Account.java
 3. Event.java

Now in my code is here

```
try {
         String key = null;
          // By passing userId i'm getting Profile object
          Profile profile = xxxx(ProfileDAO.class)
              .findByAccountId(userId);
          key = profile.getAccount().getAccountSecretKey();
        } catch (Exception se) {
      }
      Event se = new Event();
      se.setId(event.getId());
      se.setType(event.getType());
      se.setUserId(userId);
      xxx(EventDAO.class).save(se);
```

At this stage, I'm getting StaleObjectStateException On Entity Account

```
stacktrace:org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.xxxxx.Account#309650]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2509)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3228)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3126)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3456)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at xxxxx.DAO.save(DAO.java:82)
    at
```

Any idea why the Account entity is staled. 
Thanks for Advance

Comment: Your code is confusing. Why do the `Exception` and `Event` have the same variable name?  Is your `catch` block intended to be empty or did you omit code? Why did you include the `try` block when it seems to have no relation to the rest of the code? Where does the `event` variable come from? I think you need to start over with a mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What are the entity relationships (what Hibernate knows) between Profile, Account, and Event?